# Flex Timer example ... Timer goes negative

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, timer, flex3

I tried this flex example from [blog.flexexamples.com](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/14/creating-a-simple-timer-in-flex-with-the-flashutilstimer-class/). This is a basic timer example.

But when timer crosses 30 min mark, it restarts automatically and starts showing negative time value`(-1,-2 ..)`.

What is the problem ? Why it is showing negative value of timer, after it crosses 30 min mark ?

**TimerDemo.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/14/creating-a-simple-timer-in-flex-with-the-flashutilstimer-class/ -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                layout="vertical"
                verticalAlign="middle"
                backgroundColor="white"
                creationComplete="init()">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.utils.Timer;
            import flash.events.TimerEvent;

            private const MIN_MASK:String = "00";
            private const SEC_MASK:String = "00";
            private const MS_MASK:String = "000";
            private const TIMER_INTERVAL:Number = 10;

            private var baseTimer:int;

            private var t:Timer;

            private function init():void {
                t = new Timer(TIMER_INTERVAL);
                t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTimer);
            }

            private function updateTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {
                var d:Date = new Date(getTimer()-baseTimer);
                var min:String = (MIN_MASK + (d.minutes - 30.0)).toString();
                var sec:String = (SEC_MASK  + d.seconds).toString();
                var ms:String = (MS_MASK + d.milliseconds).toString();
                counter.text = String(min+":"+sec+"."+ms);
            }

            private function startTimer():void {
                baseTimer = getTimer();
                t.start();
            }

            private function stopTimer():void {
                t.stop();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
        <mx:Button label="Start timer" click="startTimer()" />
        <mx:Button label="Stop timer" click="stopTimer()" />
    </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

    <mx:Label id="counter" fontSize="96" />

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: You modified the original code, what was your purpose?

Comment: I just modified this line .. `var min:String = (d.minutes - 30.0).toString();` .. bcz in the original code, the timer was starting from 30 mins onwards. I wanted it to start from 0 min...so subtracted 30 from `d.minutes` ...

Comment: Strange thing since the original does not start from 30 mins onwards but from 0. And reading the code there is no reason it would. What is your flash player version?

Comment: @Kodiak is right, maybe your system time is off?

Comment: @Kodiak If you run the code given on the link, the timer increments till it reaches 30 mins, then onwards, it turns negative. Please run that code in the given link and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do but I think I know what your problem is.
By subtracting 30 of the `min` var, you only manipulate your output. So the actual timer is still counting the real minutes.

If you want to subtract 30 minutes from your Timer you should do it when instantiating `d:Date` like so:

```
const TIME_OFFSET:int = 1800000; //milliseconds in 30 minutes (1000*60*30)

var d:Date = new Date(getTimer()-baseTimer-TIME_OFFSET);
```

Remember to also remove the `-30` for your `var min:String`

I hope this is what you're looking for.

**EDIT**

Given your comment about your `getTimer()` and `baseTimer` having a lot of difference, you should have a look at the [getTimer()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) references. It states the following:

> **Returns**
>   *int* — The number of milliseconds since the runtime was initialized (while processing ActionScript 2.0), or since the virtual machine
>   started (while processing ActionScript 3.0). If the runtime starts
>   playing one SWF file, and another SWF file is loaded later, the return
>   value is relative to when the first SWF file was loaded.

When I trace `baseTimer` and `getTimer()` within the `startTimer()` function they are always (more or less) the same. So it seems there is something off in your case.

A workaround can be using `new Date().time` class instead of `getTimer()` like so:

```
private function updateTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {

    var d:Date = new Date(new Date().time - baseTimer);
    var min:String = (MIN_MASK + d.minutes).substr(-MIN_MASK.length);
    var sec:String = (SEC_MASK + d.seconds).substr(-SEC_MASK.length);
    var ms:String = (MS_MASK + d.milliseconds).substr(-MS_MASK.length);
    counter.text = String(min + ":" + sec + "." + ms);
}

private function startTimer():void {

    baseTimer = new Date().time;

    t.start();
}
```

More info on that can be found in the [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#time)

Comment: If you run the code given on the link, the timer increments till it reaches 30 mins, then onwards, it turns negative. Please run that code in the given link and check

Comment: If I run the code from http://blog.flexexamples.com it works just fine. Could you maybe trace what values the `getTimer()` and `baseTimer` return within the `startTimer()` function?

Comment: Each time, its different. One of the time, I got this : `getTimer()` :`3511` and `baseTimer` : `4073`

Comment: hmm, when I test, they are always almost the same. So I adjusted my answer a bit to help you further.

Comment: Please can you guide me on this doubt ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446904/flex-timer-example

Comment: and btw, why the `MIN_MASK` and all are used in the example on the blog ? What could be the reason ?

Comment: the mask is used to format your counter text, so it shows the double digits. I answered your other question aswell. (maybe accept some of your questions so people will be more likely to help you in the future)

Comment: thanks for your help. Running your soln on that question  now .. Will check, if any furthur issues are coming, if not, then will accept your answer. Anyway, +1 from me :)