# Flex Timer example

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, timer, flex3

I am trying to use timer in flex. I referred to this example : [`Timer : blog.flexexamples.com`](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/14/creating-a-simple-timer-in-flex-with-the-flashutilstimer-class/).

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

> I want to start the timer, showing **minutes elapsed** since timer
>   started. It should be independent of the region you are in.(
>   irrespective of whatever zone you are in, timer should work fine in
>   every zone).
>
> Timer should continue, unless some button is clicked, where I want to
>   show the time elapsed in minutes, in an Alert Box and then timer should start again from 0 onwards.

I tried my example, but it is not working properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                layout="vertical"
                verticalAlign="middle"
                backgroundColor="white"
                creationComplete="init()">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.TimerEvent;
            import flash.utils.Timer;

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private const TIMER_INTERVAL:Number = 10;

            private var baseTimer:int;

            private var t:Timer;

            private function init():void {
                t = new Timer(TIMER_INTERVAL);
                t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTimer);
            }

            private function updateTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {
                var d:Date = new Date(getTimer()-baseTimer);
                var min:String = (d.minutes).toString();
                var sec:String = (d.seconds).toString();

                counter.text = String(min+"."+sec);
            }

            private function startTimer():void {

                baseTimer = getTimer();
                t.start();
            }

            private function stopTimer():void {
                t.stop();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
        <mx:Button label="Start timer" click="startTimer()" />
        <mx:Button label="Stop timer" click="stopTimer()" />
    </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

    <mx:Label id="counter" fontSize="96" />
</mx:Application>
```

---

Can somebody tell what is the problem ? How to solve it ?

**EDIT :** 
If I run this example on my pc, timer starts from 30.0 till it reaches 59.59 and then it turns back to 0.0 and then starts again......Now What I want is to start from 0.0 and continue counting minutes till some button is clicked ... and this should work in any time zones

Comment: You should be the one to tell what the problem is!  What's going wrong? How can we help?  "It's not working" really doesn't give any clues.

Comment: If I run this example on my pc, timer starts from 30.0 till it reaches 59.59 and then it turns back to 0.0 and then starts again......What I want is to start from 0.0 and continue counting minutes till some button is clicked ... and this should work in any time zones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use case does not require the use of Date() and/or time zones.  All you need to do is count the seconds elapsed, and Timer offers you an easy way to do this: Set the interval to 1000 (One count per second) and use `Timer.currentCount`.  Then all you need to do is calculate minutes and seconds for display.  Below is an implementation you can incorporate into your existing mxml:

```
private function init():void {
    t = new Timer(1000);
    t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTimer);
}

// it's good practice to separate event handler from functional method
private function updateTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    display (t.currentCount);
}

private function display ( count : int ) : void {
    var minutes : int = count / 60; // divide by 60 to get the minutes
    var seconds : int = count % 60; // use modulo operator to get the "rest"
    var min : String = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : "" + minutes; // add leading zero if necessary
    var sec : String = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : "" + seconds;

    counter.text = min+":"+sec; // no need to cast to String if you use "" + something
}

private function startTimer():void {
    t.start();
}

private function stopTimer():void {
    t.stop();
    t.reset();
    display (0); // reset the display
}
```

Comment: Will this work irrespective of time zones ? I mean no issues with UTC here ?

Comment: and when it goes beyond 60 min mark, I want it to continue showing time in minutes only.. like this .. `61:15` .. 61 min, 15 sec elapsed ..

Comment: Both is true for this example: There is no UTC when you simply count the number of times the timer is called. And since there is no "hours", the minutes will keep increasing.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) ... I am running your code .. Will accept your answer once no issue comes .. Anyway, already +1 from me for this answer ..

Answer (score 0):

The example you're referring to is making things a bit to complicated for your particular problem. Here is a little example of how you can show the minutes with a simple `Timer`:

```
private const TIMER_INTERVAL:Number = 1000*60;
private var t:Timer;

private function init():void {
    t = new Timer(TIMER_INTERVAL);
    t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTimer);
    counter.text = "0";
}

private function updateTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {

    counter.text = String(t.currentCount);
}

private function startTimer():void {

    t.start();
}

private function stopTimer():void {

    t.stop();

    // if you want the timer to reset make sure to reset your text also
    /*
    t.reset();
    counter.text = "0";
    */
}
```

Comment: I ran your code .. but, still after 5 mins .. it is showing `0` only .. time isn't changing ..

Comment: and when it goes beyond 60 min mark, I want it to continue showing time in minutes only.. like this .. 61:15 .. 61 min, 15 sec elapsed

Comment: Your TIMER_INTERVAL is 60 * 1000 milliseconds == 1 minute.

Comment: In the OP he's asking for `showing minutes elapsed` so that's why I choose for the simplest way. Your solution is more complete (hence my +1) (@tomjerry when I test the code I can get past the 5 minute mark btw)